# xml serializer, don't serialize top class?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have written my code to serialize a class.  It all works fine, but i do not want my top class to be included in the serialization, what is the best way to do this?

example classes:

```
[XmlRoot(elementName: "ArrayOfDebtor")]
    public class TrustIt
    {
        [XmlArray]
        public List<Debtor> ArrayOfDebtor { get; set; }
    }

    public class Debtor
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ImportCode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public string Number { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string ParentDebtorNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string AdditionalName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string CustomEmail { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string AccountManagerEmail { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string InternalEmail { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Contact { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string InternalCreditLimit { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string ExternalCreditLimit { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Accountmanager { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string VATNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string PaymentCondition { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string CoCNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string PostAddressLine1 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string PostPostalCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string PostCity { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string ExternalCreditLimitValidFrom { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string ExternalCreditLimitValidTo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string ExternalCreditLimitType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string CreditInsurerNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlArray]
        public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    }

    public class Invoice
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ImportCode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public string Number { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Date { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string DueDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string AmountVAT { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string OpenAmount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string ManualLeading { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string IncludeInCorrespondence { get; set; }
    }
```

the output i desire is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfDebtor>
<Debtor ImportCode="ImportCode1" LanguageCode="AR" CountryCode="AF">
<Number>AR001</Number>
<ParentDebtorNumber>AQ1</ParentDebtorNumber>
<Name>Soapystuff n.v.</Name>
<AdditionalName>Soapystuff</AdditionalName>
<AddressLine1>Zeepstraat 15</AddressLine1>
<AddressLine2>bus2</AddressLine2>
<AddressLine3></AddressLine3>
<PostalCode>1000 AA</PostalCode>
<City>Amsterdam</City>
<Telephone>01-4789-457-11</Telephone>
<Mobile>06-456-789-78</Mobile>
<Fax>12364111</Fax>
<Email>info@soapystuff.nl</Email>
<CustomEmail>sales@soapystuff.nl</CustomEmail>
<AccountManagerEmail>accountmanager@tkb.nl</AccountManagerEmail>
<InternalEmail>info@tkb.nl</InternalEmail>
<Contact>mr A. Van dingenen</Contact>
<InternalCreditLimit>100000</InternalCreditLimit>
<ExternalCreditLimit>2000</ExternalCreditLimit>
<Category>B</Category>
<Accountmanager>mevr savon</Accountmanager>
<VATNumber></VATNumber>
<PaymentCondition>30 dagen</PaymentCondition>
<CoCNumber>12.345.678</CoCNumber>
<PostAddressLine1>Maanstraat 12</PostAddressLine1>
<PostPostalCode>1000 AA</PostPostalCode>
<PostCity>Amsterdam</PostCity>
<ExternalCreditLimitValidFrom>2013-01-01</ExternalCreditLimitValidFrom>
<ExternalCreditLimitValidTo>2014-12-31</ExternalCreditLimitValidTo>
<ExternalCreditLimitType></ExternalCreditLimitType>
<CreditInsurerNumber>12345</CreditInsurerNumber>
<Invoices>
<Invoice ImportCode="ImportCode1" CurrencyCode="AUD">
<Number>FN0000111</Number>
<Date>2011-08-01</Date>
<DueDate>2011-09-01</DueDate>
<Amount>1200.45</Amount>
<AmountVAT>120</AmountVAT>
<OpenAmount>1000</OpenAmount>
<ManualLeading>true</ManualLeading>
<Reference>123456</Reference>
<Description></Description>
<OrderNumber>5467</OrderNumber>
<CustomFields>
<CustomField Code="invoiceReference">XS001Ref2</CustomField>
<CustomField Code="StartDate">
2011-01-01T00:00:00</CustomField>
</CustomFields>
</Invoice>
<Invoice ImportCode="ImportCode2" CurrencyCode="AUD">
<Number>FN0000112</Number>
<Date>2011-08-11</Date>
<DueDate>2011-09-10</DueDate>
<Amount>1200.45</Amount>
<AmountVAT>120</AmountVAT>
<OpenAmount>1000</OpenAmount>
<CustomFields>
TKB IT Solutions – XML-specificaties TRUST IT
<CustomField Code="invoiceOtherCodeReference">XSRef2
</CustomField>
<CustomField Code="StartDate">
2011-01-01T12:30:00</CustomField>
</CustomFields>
</Invoice>
<Invoice ImportCode="ImportCode3" CurrencyCode="AUD">
<Number>FN0000113</Number>
<Date>2011-09-11</Date>
<DueDate>2011-11-10</DueDate>
<Amount>100.45</Amount>
<OpenAmount>75</OpenAmount>
</Invoice>
</Invoices>
<CustomFields>
<CustomField Code="debiteurReferentie">DebRef0001</CustomField>
<CustomField Code="DebiteurFinalDate">
2011-12-31T00:00:00</CustomField>
</CustomFields>
</Debtor>
<Debtor ImportCode="ImportCode2" LanguageCode="NL" CountryCode="NL">
<Number>DB0234</Number>
<Name>autos Verstraeten bvba</Name>
<Category>P</Category>
<Invoices>
<Invoice ImportCode="ImportCode1" CurrencyCode="AUD">
<Number>FN0000111</Number>
<Date>2011-08-01</Date>
<DueDate>2011-09-01</DueDate>
<Amount>1200.45</Amount>
<AmountVAT>120</AmountVAT>
<OpenAmount>1000</OpenAmount>
<ManualLeading>true</ManualLeading>
<CustomFields>
<CustomField Code="invoiceReference">XS001Ref2</CustomField>
<CustomField Code="StartDate">
2011-01-01T00:00:00
</CustomField>
</CustomFields>
</Invoice>
</Invoices>
</Debtor>
<Debtor ImportCode="ImportCode3" LanguageCode="NL" CountryCode="NL">
<Number>Q475AAAA</Number>
<Name>security Secure-it</Name>
<Category>B</Category>
</Debtor>
</ArrayOfDebtor>
```

my code to serialize:

```
TrustIt.TrustIt xmlObj = new TrustIt.TrustIt();
            xmlObj.ArrayOfDebtor = new List<TrustIt.Debtor>();

            //Debtor 1
            TrustIt.Debtor Debtor = randomize<TrustIt.Debtor>(new TrustIt.Debtor());
            Debtor.Name = "Debtor Name 1";
            TrustIt.Invoice invoice1 = randomize<TrustIt.Invoice>(new TrustIt.Invoice());
            invoice1.ImportCode = "INV001";
            invoice1.CurrencyCode = "EUR";

            TrustIt.Invoice invoice2 = randomize<TrustIt.Invoice>(new TrustIt.Invoice());
            invoice2.ImportCode = "INV002";
            invoice2.CurrencyCode = "EUR";

            TrustIt.Invoice invoice3 = randomize<TrustIt.Invoice>(new TrustIt.Invoice());
            invoice3.ImportCode = "INV003";
            invoice3.CurrencyCode = "EUR";

            TrustIt.Invoice invoice4 = randomize<TrustIt.Invoice>(new TrustIt.Invoice());
            invoice4.ImportCode = "INV004";
            invoice4.CurrencyCode = "EUR";

            Debtor.Invoices = new List<TrustIt.Invoice>();
            Debtor.Invoices.Add(invoice1);
            Debtor.Invoices.Add(invoice2);
            Debtor.Invoices.Add(invoice3);
            Debtor.Invoices.Add(invoice4);

            xmlObj.ArrayOfDebtor.Add(Debtor);

            //Debtor 2
            Debtor = randomize<TrustIt.Debtor>(new TrustIt.Debtor());
            Debtor.Name = "Debtor Name 1";
            invoice1 = randomize<TrustIt.Invoice>(new TrustIt.Invoice());
            invoice1.ImportCode = "INV010";
            invoice1.CurrencyCode = "EUR";

            invoice2 = randomize<TrustIt.Invoice>(new TrustIt.Invoice());
            invoice2.ImportCode = "INV011";
            invoice2.CurrencyCode = "EUR";

            invoice3 = randomize<TrustIt.Invoice>(new TrustIt.Invoice());
            invoice3.ImportCode = "INV012";
            invoice3.CurrencyCode = "EUR";

            invoice4 = randomize<TrustIt.Invoice>(new TrustIt.Invoice());
            invoice4.ImportCode = "INV013";
            invoice4.CurrencyCode = "EUR";

            Debtor.Invoices = new List<TrustIt.Invoice>();
            Debtor.Invoices.Add(invoice1);
            Debtor.Invoices.Add(invoice2);
            Debtor.Invoices.Add(invoice3);
            Debtor.Invoices.Add(invoice4);

            xmlObj.ArrayOfDebtor.Add(Debtor);

            XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TrustIt.TrustIt));
            string xml = "";
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
                {
                    xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, xmlObj);
                    xml = sw.ToString(); // Your XML
                }
            }
```

So either i have TrustIt at the start and end of my xml, which shouldn't be there, or now when adding the XmlRoot Attribute i have twice the ArrayOfDebtor in my xml output.  How can i prevent this?

Comment: I have fixed that

Comment: To remove the top level class would mean the root level of the xml would be an array (Not Well Formed) of elements and Xml Serialization only works with Well Formed Xml.  You can can have an array at root, but you would not be able to use the Net Library XmlSerialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfDebtor")]
public class TrustIt
{
    [XmlElement("Debtor")] // <==== this is the change
    public List<Debtor> ArrayOfDebtor { get; set; }
}
```